# MATCH AGAINST multiple words AND OR

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, match, against

I am using fulltext search in a project. I want to search multiple words but i have a problem. So my query is;

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM table
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2) AGAINST ('+(word1) +(word2) +(word3 word4)')
GROUP BY col1
ORDER BY 1 desc limit 12
```

And this query is searches including word1 OR word2 OR **word3 OR word4**
but i want to search including word1 OR word2 OR **word3 word4**

So what is the solution?

Comment: Please refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html), it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this one...

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table WHERE MATCH(colname1,colname2) AGAINST("keyword to search")  GROUP BY colname ORDER BY colname desc limit 12
```

[Reference](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/match-against/)

Comment: is it not possible with MATCH AGAINST?

Comment: @pheaselegen `MATCH` and `AGAINST` two different thing..  :/

Comment: You edited your post? You learned MATCH AGAINST? So what is my question's answer? I know how to use MATCH AGAINST. So you wrote this. But my question is different :)

Comment: yes i edited my post, please check my post and link, which i have used to refer.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` 
WHERE MATCH (`first_name`,`last_name`) 
      AGAINST ('(+bruce+wayne)(+clark+kent)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```